# Level Sets, Curves, and Surfaces

Tags: analysis, graphing-functions

I'm studying about the functions and one chapter is about level sets, curves and surfaces. Is there a software which can help me to generate automatically level curves.

Also if you can help me with the graph of $\displaystyle z=x^2-y^2$ and its level curves.

Thanks :)

Comment: @Downvoter Why (-1) vote ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Maple for doing this so easily. It is one of user friendly Maths software.

Type the below commend in one worksheet in Maple and then "Enter":

> plot3d(x^2-y^2,x=-10..10,y=-10..10);

you will see:

[image]

and by cliking right on the shape you see:

[image]

Now choose the *contour*, so you have:

[image]

Comment: Just beautiful, Babak!

Answer (score 1):

Maple is a good piece of software. However, I am more comfortable using Mathematica which in my opinion is more user friendly and functional. Also, you can use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z=x2%E2%88%92y2), a very useful website. If you type in google "graph z=x^2-y^2" it will also plot a graph for you. There is plenty of ways to generate graphs without buying or obtaining costly math software.